# How to create custom notification layout in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

i want to create my own notification layout for android and iOS. i am using react-native-push-notification library, but i am not able to get any idea that how we can create our own notification layout.[image]

Comment: Hi. i want to do same. any update?

Comment: @kamleshparmar  not yet.